# Simplifying `if` statements in Tic Tac Toe function

Tags: c#, game

I'm currently trying to improve my coding skills, so I'm trying to code a *Tic Tac Toe* game. At one point a "win check" is needed.

I'm using this code to check:

```
public void CheckWin(States state)
{   
    if(fieldA1.GetState == state && fieldA2.GetState == state && fieldA3.GetState == state)
        ReportWin(currentPlayer);
    else if(fieldB1.GetState == state && fieldB2.GetState == state && fieldB3.GetState == state)
        ReportWin(currentPlayer);
    else if (fieldC1.GetState == state && fieldC2.GetState == state && fieldC3.GetState == state)
        ReportWin(currentPlayer);
    else if (fieldA1.GetState == state && fieldB1.GetState == state && fieldC1.GetState == state)
        ReportWin(currentPlayer);
    else if (fieldA2.GetState == state && fieldB2.GetState == state && fieldC2.GetState == state)
        ReportWin(currentPlayer);
    else if (fieldA2.GetState == state && fieldB2.GetState == state && fieldC2.GetState == state)
        ReportWin(currentPlayer);
    else if (fieldA3.GetState == state && fieldB3.GetState == state && fieldC3.GetState == state)
        ReportWin(currentPlayer);
    else if (fieldA1.GetState == state && fieldB2.GetState == state && fieldC3.GetState == state)
        ReportWin(currentPlayer);
    else if (fieldA3.GetState == state && fieldB2.GetState == state && fieldC1.GetState == state)
        ReportWin(currentPlayer);
    else
        PlayerSwitch();
}
```

This code looks very unclean to me.  Is there a better way to handle these `if` instructions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There should only be eight ways to win; you have nine `ReportWin()`s.  This one got listed twice:

```
fieldA2.GetState == state && fieldB2.GetState == state && fieldC2.GetState == state
```

Considering that you've named your squares as independent variables, there's not much you can do to generalize `CheckWin()`.  Start by turning the board into an  array or two-dimensional array, then read the advice in [Tic-Tac-Toe design](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/31769/9357) .  Personally, I like the suggestion to [list all eight winning configurations](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/31790/9357), as it results in the least code.

Comment: Yes, you're right! Thank you for bringing me in the right direction, this helped me alot!

Answer (score 1):

I am too lazy to program it, but try programming tic tac toe instead of being in the "bruteforce" way, try making the winner the one who has at least 3 picks and the sum of his picks is 15(bad wording, I know). I'm going to save you on my blabbering and look at this:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_square

Comment: Uhm I never heard of the real way to play this, I only knew the basic "children game". Looks like there is much more behind this game, thank you for showing me this!